# how to merge a new workspace with existing remote repository in bit bucket

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket, git-merge, remote-repository

I have a remote repository, lets call it as release1 , and apparently for some reason I have to keep a back up and started working on new functionality in new workspace lets call it as workspace_new just not to mess up the old code, workspace_new which I currently have in eclipse is not connected to release1,

now I want to merge workspace_new with my release1 which already has my old code, how can i make connection and merge the code,

sorry it may be stupid and basic question for many, but I am new to this

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you just need to add the remote repo to your local repo:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:sarath/release1.git
```

Replacing the git url with the url of your repo

Then you should be able to commit and merge the code:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: If it worked for you i would appreciate the answer upvote :)